# Rest Service which gets details based on IP address

Tags: java, google-maps, rest, spring-mvc

I have to write a restful web service which takes a user ip address as a input and the response output has to be the location , city , state and country and zip code. So based on the user IP address, how can i get the user details. Is there any api for that? By using google maps api , can we achieve that? I need to save those user location details in database
Please help me how to approach to write a restful webservice for the above requirement?

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many providers for this kind of task. I used the free database from http://dev.maxmind.com once.